# Can't get 3 plots in one picture

Tags: matplotlib

I'd like to plot 3 function in one picture,but the third can't get,Is there anything with my code?

```
x = np.arange(-10., 10., 0.2)
simod1=sigmoid(x)
tanh1=tanh1(x)
relu1=relu(x)
pl.figure(num=1, figsize=(8, 6)) 
pl.title('Plot 1', size=14)
pl.xlabel('x-axis', size=14)
pl.ylabel('y-axis', size=14)

pl.plot(x, simod1, color='b', linestyle='--', marker='o', label='sigmoid')
pl.plot(x, tanh1, color='r', linestyle='-', label='tanh')
pl.plot(x, relu1, color='y', linestyle='*', label='relu')
pl.legend(loc='upper left')
pl.savefig('temp.png', format='png')
```

Answer (score 1):

`'*'` is not a valid `linestyle` see the documentation http://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_linestyle

I think you want to do this instead:

```
plt.plot(x, simod1, 'o--', color='b', label='sigmoid')
plt.plot(x, tanh1, '-', color='r', label='tanh')
plt.plot(x, relu1, '*', color='y', label='relu')
```